# Where should MQClient.ini reside for an IIS Application?

Tags: c#, iis, ibm-mq

I've got an web application (WebApi2 / c#) installed under an IIS Web Site that needs to use an IBM WebSphere MQ `mqclient.ini` file.

Where's the ini file supposed to reside?  I've tried in the application's `bin` folder, as well as `%system32%\inetsvr`, with no luck.

Hoping someone can point out where this is supposed to reside, as I haven't been able to locate the correct location via IBM's documentation...

Comment: Is a global `mqclient.ini` acceptable for the whole Windows server or do you require the ability to specify different `mqclient.ini` files per application in the IIS Web server?

Comment: Global is totally fine lol

Comment: This may be helpful. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q016850_.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The locations where MQ Client will look for the `mqclient.ini` file are documented in the IBM MQ v7.5 (or later) Knowledge Center page "[Location of the client configuration file](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q016850_.htm)":

A MQ client app will look in locations below in order from 1 to 4 for the file.  This is a summary of the above KC page with some additional notes from me:

1. If you just want to set a global location you can set a server environment variable called `MQCLNTCF` to point to the path and file name of your mqclient.ini file.
2. `mqclient.ini` in the present working directory of the application.  In our testing we could not get this to work for a IIS application.
3. `mqclient.ini` in the Data directory where MQ is installed, you can check this location by looking at the `MQ_FILE_PATH` environment variable.
4. `mqclient.ini` in the directory consisting of the concatenated values of the `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH` environment variables.

---

In addition if you are using Managed .NET client another option is to place settings in the application's `app.config` or `web.config` file.  This is documented in the IBM MQ v7.5 (or later) Knowledge Center at the bottom of the page "[Configuration files for WebSphere MQ classes for .NET](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q029490_.htm)".  This page provides an example that you can use as a model for any of the settings that are honored by the Managed .Net client.

Comment: That is precisely what I sought!  Thank you, sir, I'll test tomorrow and report back.